# Turn off unobtrusive validation runtime?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, unobtrusive-javascript

I have my MVC 3 application with unobtrusive validation. In one of view present `<form action=''>..</form>` and there I have two buttons. First button submit form on 'action1' and second button submit to 'action2'. In first case I have to validate form, but in second case I need to make post, without validation, is it possible? Currently model validates in both cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer. To disable validation on 'action2' I have to execute in controller the next method:

```
ModelState.Clear();
```

and in view

```
Html.EnableClientValidation(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Been a while since i've done Asp.net MVC, is this what you're looking for ?

```
@if(false) { // Replace false with your model property
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options:

1)  Do not use ModelState.IsValid in the Controller action.  On action1, run a javascript method that validates the Form.  If the Form is valid then submit the form.  On action2, since you are not using ModelState.IsValid, submit the form and you controller action will run.

2)  Use ModelState.IsValid in the Controller action.  Name the two submit buttons the same name (i.e., 'SubmitButton').  Assign 'action1' and 'action2' as the values for the respective submit buttons.  Pass SubmitButton as a string parameter to the Controller action.  If SubmitButton = 'action1' query ModelState.IsValid.  Else, do not query ModelState.IsValid.

Option2 Code

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeAction(ModelObject theModel, string SubmitButton)
{
    if (SubmitButton== 'Action1')
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //do some work
        } 
        else
        {
            return(View(theModel));
        } 

    }
    else //action2 has ben used to submit, so don't vaildate
    {
       //do some work
    }
}
```

View:

```
<input type="submit" id="action1" name="SubmitButton" value="Action1"/> 
<input type="submit" id="action2" name="SubmitButton" value="Action2"/>
```